# How to a separate ASP.Net Core Application using same Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an existing ASP.Net Core Web API and now I want to create the admin module as a separate ASP.Net Core application but sharing the same database.

My problem now is how to handle my DBContext in the new solution especially because of the the following line containing the ApplicationUser model

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

and also the other model classes which exist in the existing solution from where I need to create my DBSet entitie sets to enable me query the database.

I wish to have the admin module to be a completely separate application hosted on a different domain/server but having access to the same database so that the admin can manage the database table entries from the admin solution.

I don't want it to be a separate project on the same solution. Rather I want it to be a completely separate solution/application which can be hosted independently.

I will appreciate any guide to achieving this if it is possible with ASP.Net Core.

I am using ASP.Net Core 5 with Entity Framework Core but I can migrate to version 6 if that offers a solution.

Comment: I would start by completely separating `ApplicationDbContext` and `IdentityDbContext`. But we can only give opinions and suggestions here.

Comment: @GertArnold your opinion and suggestions are highly welcome. Please go ahead and explain how to go about it

Comment: No, Stack Overflow is not the right platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a model as a separate (third) project, build a `nuget` of that Model project and include it in both. There are some small challenges, since you are going to run migrations on this standalone project - but nothing that cannot be overcome

It's very straightforward (and possible since `ASP.NET Core 1`).

Comment: Can the models be a class library instead of a nugget? Or could you explain more why it has to be a nugget

Comment: First, it's `nuget`, not nugget. Second - and more important, it *is* class library. nuget is the easier way to package class library, and include in other projects. But if you want more pain - sure, you can just fight unpackaged DLLs

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a shot and revert

Comment: Do you mean that the DBContext and the models would be the make-up of the 3rd standalone application?

Comment: @Josh - yes, exactly

Comment: I guess this implies that while creating the project in Visual Studio, I should choose Class Library as the type of project and not Web Application of any sort. Right?

Comment: In .Net Core you don't have "Web Application". In the output type web applications are Console Application. So, I have this library as Console Application as well; although it is built as DLL and packaged as nuget package. The other choices are Class Library and Windows application; but frankly, I don't know what is the difference between Class Library and Console Application in this context

Comment: Thank you. It is going well so far. My next question is, "Since this is not a package for the public, is there a way to store it outside nuget.org and be able to pull it into my application from that platform/location whenever I need it in any project?"

Comment: Yes, you can store it anywhere you want - like in a directory on your drive (or on the network if you want to share it). You can define the location in package sources in Visual Studio

Comment: Thank you. I have done that successfully. Stores on my local directory

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple contexts for single database. It can be useful for example if your database contains multiple database schemas and you want to handle each of them as separate self contained area.

Read the link below

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_multiple_dbcontext.htm

Comment: This has nothing to do with original question - but hey, it may help somebody else